# vigenere cipher c language

Tags: c, if-statement, encryption, vigenere

I am trying to make a vigenere cipher in C language. The input is only supposed to be alphabetical characters (a->z).

Currently my issue is the output only puts out 4 characters and outputs strange characters outside the alphabet. I have created the if statements to prevent this, but it seems they are not working. Any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int i=0;
//Vigenere Cipher-- keyword is "apple"
//a = 1  value shift
//p = 16 value shift
//p = 16 value shift
//l = 17 value shift
//e = 5  value shift
 //cleaning out string array
 char guy[100];

printf("Enter the plain text: ");
fgets(guy, 100, stdin);//takes user's input

while (guy[i] != '\0'){ //while loop that runs until it reaches the end of the string

    if ((i%5==0) || i==0){ //checks to see which character it is in the string, for instance the numbers 0,5,10,15,20 should all be added by 1
    guy[i] = guy[i]+1;
    if (guy[i]>'z' && guy[i]<'A'){
            guy[i]-25;
    }
    if (guy[i]>'Z' && guy[i]>'A'){
        guy[i]-25;
    }
    }

    if (((i-1)%5==0) || i==1){ //all numbers that are second in the key word 'apple', such as 1,6,11,16
        guy[i]=guy[i]+16;
        if (guy[i]>'z' && guy[i]<'A'){
            guy[i]-25;
        }
        if (guy[i]>'Z' && guy[i]>'A'){
            guy[i]-25;
        }
    }
    if (((i-2)%5==0) || i==2){// all numbers that are third to the key word 'apple' , such as 2,7,12,17,22
        guy[i]=guy[i]+16;
        if (guy[i]>'z'&& guy[i]<'A'){
            guy[i]-25;
        }
        if (guy[i]>'Z'&& guy[i]>'A'){
            guy[i]-25;
        }
    }
    if(((i-3)%5==0) || i==3){// all numbers that are fourth to the key word 'apple', such as 3,8,13,18
        guy[i]=guy[i]+17;
        if (guy[i]>'z'&&guy[i]<'A'){//takes care of z
            guy[i]-25;
    }
        if (guy[i]>'Z' && guy[i]>'A'){//takes care of Z
            guy[i]-25;
        }
    }
    if(((i-4)%5==0) || i==4){// all numbers that are fifth in the key word 'apple', such as 4,9,14,19
        guy[i]=guy[i]+5;
        if (guy[i]>'z'&& guy[i]<'A'){
            guy[i]-25;
        }
        if (guy[i]>'Z' && guy[i]>'A'){
            guy[i]-25;
        }
    }
    else {
    i++;
    }
    }
printf("Encrypted text is: %s\n",guy);
}
```

Comment: You really need to write a function `char encrypt_char(char plain_text, char key)` then call it with `guy[i] = encrypt_char(guy[i], "apple"[i%5]);`. Furthermore, `if (guy[i]>'Z'&& guy[i]>'A')` is the same as `if (guy[i]>'Z')`. You also ought to learn how to use a debugger so you can step through and see what is happening, and also think about how should a SPACE or digit, etc, should be encrypted, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have a function encrypt_char() which does encryption for you.

```
void encrypt_char(char *character, unsigned int offset)
{
    if('a' <= *character && 'z' >= *character)
    {
        *character = ((*character + offset - 'a') % 26) + 'a';
    } 
    else if('A' <= *character && 'Z' >= *character)
    {
        *character = ((*character + offset - 'A') % 26) + 'A';
    }
}
```

Call it with your offset value.

```
if (i%5==0){
    encrypt_char(&(guy[i]), 1);
} else if ((i-1)%5==0){
     encrypt_char(&(guy[i]), 16);
} else...
```

Comment: The `|| i==0` etc are of course not needed as `0%5 == 0`, etc.

Comment: yeah! I just copied the code from question. Removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than give the whole game away, here is some code (untested!) based on my comment:

```
char encrypt_char(char plain_text, char key)
{
    char offset = tolower(key) - 'a' + 1;
    if (islower(plain_text))
        return (plain_text - 'a' + 1 + offset) % 26 + 'a';
    else if (isupper(plain_text))
        return (plain_text - 'A' + 1 + offset) % 26 + 'A';
    else
        return plain_text;
}
```

This might be off by one somewhere along the way, so have fun debugging!

Comment: Offset calculation looks wrong (Or it is wrong in question!).  'p' should be 16 and 'l' should be 17 according to the question. I think there should be a lookup table.

Comment: I mention above it gets called with `encrypt_char(guy[i], "apple"[i%5])`.

Comment: I understand that. What I am saying is the key is not the index of character in alphabet set. If understand your logic correctly offset values for {a,p,p,l,e} is {1, 16, 16,  12, 5} which is wrong. It should be {1, 16, 16, 17, 5}. Hope I make sense!

Comment: @MayurK I suspect that `17` is an error as it is stated `apple`, not `appqe` is the key...